# Running Subprocess from Python

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I want to run a cmd exe using a python script.

I have the following code:

```
def run_command(command):
    p = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    return p.communicate()
```

then i use: 
run_command(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\application\uploader.exe") 
this returns the option menu where i need to specify additional parameter for the cmd exe to run. So i pass additional parameters for the cmd exe to run. 
How do i accomplish this. I've looked at subprocess.communicate but i was unable to understand it

Comment: Sometimes you can add `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` and then write what the program expects in communicate, as in `p.communicate("what the program wants")`. If you really need somthing interactive, you're in trouble. Its an easy enough thing on unix-y systems - just use pexpect to drive the interactive prompt. But I don't know any canned solutions in windows. You can use win32 and create a console window for the process, but its hard to figure out and get right.

Answer (score 0):

If `uploader.exe` accepts command line options, then you could try `subprocess.call` in the following manner:

If your command is `uploader.exe`, the directory of uploader is `C:\Users\...\application`, and the additional parameter is `x`, you could try

```
import subprocess
def run_command(command, directory, arg):
    return subprocess.call(["command %s"%arg], cwd=directory, shell=True)

run_command("uploader.exe", "C:\\Users\\..\\application", "x")
```

However, this assumes you do not need to actually interact with `indexer.exe` after you `Popen` to it.

Comment: This is a great answer if upload.exe can accomplish its task with command line arguments.

Comment: How do i make the console window stay open? after running "run_command"